Is this matrix semi-positive-definite: $(|A_i \cup A_j|^{-s})_{n\times n}$?

Let $$M = (|A_i \cup A_j|^{-s})$$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, where $s >0, \mathrm{nonempty  \,set\,} A_i \subset \{1,2,3,\cdots,k\},$ and $|\cdot|$ stands for the cardinal of the set. 
Prove that $M$ is semi-positive-definite.

My attempt:
Since:$$M=(|A_i \cup A_j|^{-s})=((k-|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|)^{-s})=k^{-s}((1-|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|/k)^{-s})$$
And we have $0 \leq |A_i^c \cap A_j^c| \leq k-1, 0 \leq |A_i^c \cap A_j^c| \leq \dfrac{k-1}{k}<1$, so:
$$(1-|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|/k)^{-s}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty {{-s}\choose{r}}(-|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|/k)^r,{{-s}\choose{r}}(-1/k)^r>0.$$
Therefore:
$$M=\sum_{r=0}^\infty {{-s}\choose{r}}(-1/k)^r (|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|)^r.$$
If we can prove  $N:=(|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|)$ is semi-positive-definite, for Hadamard product, we can imply that $M$ is semi-positive-definite then. To prove that, we can define a "characteristic function":
$$\chi_A= \left \{ \begin{aligned}
1 \text{ on } [t-1,t],& &t \in A, \\
0 \text{ on } [t-1,t],& &\text{otherwise.}
\end{aligned} \right. $$
And we have $$\sum_{i,j}|A_i^c \cap A_j^c|x_iy_j=\sum_{i,j}\int_0^\infty \chi_{A_i^c}\chi_{A_j^c}\mathrm{d}x \, x_iy_j=\int_0^\infty \sum_{i,j}\chi_{A_i^c}\chi_{A_j^c} \, x_iy_j\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty\sum_{i}(\chi_{A_i^c} \, x_i)^2\mathrm{d}x\geq 0.$$
Therefore $N$ is semi-positive-definite.
My question:
Is my proof right? In fact, I was trying solving the problem in another way, like the posts $\frac1{(a_i+a_j)^\alpha}$ and $t^{|A_i \cap A_j|}$, by using Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion. $$\begin{align*}
x^TMx 
&= \sum_{i, j} x_i x_j |A_i \cup A_j|^{-s} \\
&= \frac{1}{C_s} \sum_{i, j} x_i x_j \int_0^\infty e^{-|A_i \cup A_j|t^{1/s}} \,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{C_s} \sum_{i, j} x_i x_j \int_0^\infty e^{(-|A_i| - |A_j| + |A_i \cap A_j|) t^{1/s}} \,dt 
\end{align*}$$
We may know that $(e\text{^}t\text{^1/}s)^{|A_i \cap A_j|}$ is semi-positive-definite, for $(e\text{^}t\text{^1/}s) \geq 1$,  but I do not know how to deal with $(e\text{^}t\text{^1/}s)^{(-|A_i| - |A_j| + |A_i \cap A_j|)}$ together.
Are there any simple viewpoints of this problem?
